# buildr create a jar that include libs and other project

Tags: java, buildr

I have 2 Java projects (eg p1 and p2) and I want to create jar (using buildr) that contains both projects and their libs.

p2 depends on p1.

```
compile.with(projects('p1'), removeDups(project('p1').compile.dependencies), removeDups(P2_LIBS))

package(:jar).with( :manifest => {'Main-Class' => 'com.p2.Main'} )

compile.dependencies.each do |x|
         if x 
            package(:jar).merge(x).exclude('META-INF/MANIFEST.MF')
         end
end
```

I tried this, but that give me an error, I think because p2 depends on p1, because if I have only p1 and libs this works.

So how should I create the jar file with p1, p2 an libs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a packaging project that packages both.

See examples [here](https://github.com/atoulme/logBot/blob/master/Buildfile) and [here](https://github.com/intalio/wapama/blob/master/Buildfile).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a JAR file for p1 using any IDE (netbeans for example)?  It will be on your dist directory, include it in the libraries path for p2 then build p2 and get its Jar.